# How to test DOM sensitivities with intern

Tags: dom, testing, intern

I would like to test some DOM related things with intern, nothing requiring specific fixtures, just general DOM stuff like if I mutated the Element.prototype. Does that require a functional test run through a local Selenium Server (or sauce labs) or can that be done through the non-functional testing suite?

Answer (score 1):

Intern doesn’t provide sandboxing to isolate unit test suites, so if you’re going to modify native objects for the purposes of testing, you’ll either need to restore them yourself later (in your suite teardown) or create your own sandboxing (by creating a new document or a new frame, depending upon what you are actually trying to test). You don’t need to use functional testing unless you’re trying to test things that can’t be reliably done from within the JavaScript sandbox (certain types of events, file uploads, multi-page navigation, cross-frame scripting, probably some other things).

Comment: What would be the best way to simulate the DOM in the node runner so I can run the tests from the command line?

Comment: If you’re using the test runner (`runner.js`), the unit tests run in the browser environments [you specify in `environments`](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Configuring-Intern). You should never simulate anything if you’re trying to get real answers. There is no way to use the Node.js client (`client.js`) to perform DOM tests. The closest you can get in that case is [PhantomJS](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Using-Intern-with-PhantomJS).

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. In order to do that, I would have to use the Geezer version of intern which I'm not crazy about. Guess I'll just run in the browser. Thank you.